# Hasura @skip where condition in query

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have two models, user and accounts. A user can have zero or more accounts. I can fetch all the users (with and without accounts) with the below query.

I also want to filter the users based on the account name for which I'm using the _ilike operator in line 14.

However, this will also return users with no accounts. How can we avoid this?
[image]

Is there a way skip the condition in the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

{} evaluates to true if any object exists. so you can use the _and operator as

```
_and: [
    {
      accounts: { name: { _ilike: $accountName } }
    },
    {
      accounts: {}
    }
]
```